# I get different results for same image in a program

Tags: c++, opencv, image-processing

I made a small program that calculates the number of white pixels in a grayscale image. I get different results if I open the image twice in the same program. Same if I display the intensity of the pixels, it changes even if it is the same image. If anyone sees where the problem is please help.

```
#include "opencv2/imgcodecs.hpp"
#include "opencv2/highgui.hpp"
#include "opencv2/imgproc.hpp"
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;
using namespace cv;
int main()
{ int i=0,j,nbr=0,nbr1=0;


Mat image=imread("2_.png",CV_LOAD_IMAGE_GRAYSCALE);
Mat image2=imread("2_.png",CV_LOAD_IMAGE_GRAYSCALE);

for(i=0;i<image.rows;i++)
{
    for( j=0;j<image.cols;j++)
    {if (image.at<int>(i,j)!=0)
           nbr++;
     if (image2.at<int>(i,j)!=0)
           nbr1++;
    }
}
printf("%d\n %d\n",nbr,nbr1);


    return 0;}
```

Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is may be because you need to avoid using `int`, but `uchar` for grayscale image. Using `int` you go out of image memory.

Comment: Yeah, this makes sense, because if you read int every time, eventually you have buffer over read; Beyond the buffer, the data is completely garbage.

Comment: @JeruLuke The English is wrong since you edited it. Now it reads like `int` is optional rather than wrong.

Comment: Thank you it gives the same number of pixels now. is it correct to acces the pixels value like that: image.at<uchar>(i,j) ?

Comment: yes, for images with element type CV_8UC1 (grayscale). If element type is CV_32FC1 it will be image.at<float>, if it color image it will have several channels like CV_8UC3 or CV_32FC3 then it will be correct to access elements like image.at<Vec3b> for CV_8UC3 and image.at<Vec3f> for CV_32FC3.